# Rails 5.2: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (claims username is taken, although it is not)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an issue with my Rails-API, in particular ActiveRecord claims that - whenever I try to create a user - the user already existed.

This is my current setup:
Ruby -v 2.5.1p57 /
Rails 5.2 (API only)

I am using Postman to deliver an HTTP POST-request to my API-endpoint, however I can't seem to create any users whatsoever.

This is what my User-Model looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  has_secure_password
  has_secure_token :auth_token

  def invalidate_token
    self.update_columns(auth_token: nil)
  end

  def self.validate_login(username, password)
    user = find_by(username: username)
    if user && user.authenticate(password)
      user
    end
  end
end
```

I am well aware, that I validate for uniqueness of the username here, but the thing that stuns me is, for the usernames I tested within postman, no single DB-record exists.

Next up is my current version of the UsersController:

```
module Api::V1
  class UsersController < ApiController
    before_action :require_login, except: [:create]

    # GET /users
    # GET /users.json
     def index
      @users = User.all
      render json: @users
    end

    # GET /users/1
    # GET /users/1.json
    # def show
    # end

    def profile
      user = User.find_by_auth_token!(request.headers[:token])

      render json: { user: { username: user.username, email: user.email, first_name: user.first_name } }
    end

    # GET /users/new
    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    # GET /users/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /users
    # POST /users.json
    def create
      user = User.create!

      render json: { token: user.auth_token }
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /users/1
    # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(user_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich bearbeitet.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /users/1
    # DELETE /users/1.json
    def destroy
      @user.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Nutzer wurde gelöscht.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
    end
  end
end
```

This is what my rails-terminal responds when I try to POST to the endpoint:

```
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as JSON
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:35
  User Exists (5.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE 
"users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:35
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:35
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Gültigkeitsprüfung ist fehlgeschlagen: Username ist bereits vergeben, Password muss ausgefüllt werden):
```

The last string translates to: Validation failed: Username has already been taken, Password must not be empty.

Any hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at that query:

```
User Exists (5.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE 
"users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

username IS NULL

Why is the username NULL in this query? That's a good hint that your username isn't getting populated. Looking at your controller you'll spot the problem:

```
user = User.create!
```

You need to pass parameters to the create method. So this:

```
user = User.create!(user_params)
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the user_params back to the line you referred to. However, the server now replies with the following: `# .<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user>`

Comment: that's because in your `user_params` definition you have `params.require(:user)...`, which will require that in params you have `user` and then all the attributes like `user: { name: '...', lat_name: 'llll', etc, etc }`. So, in the params you're passing to your controller your missing the `user` key.

Comment: Right. To echo what @fanta said, it sounds like you aren't actually sending a "user" in your POST request. In the Rails console/log do you see a Parameters: section? What does it say? I bet there isn't a :user param. I don't know a ton about Postman, I feel like it might be easier for you just to learn and use curl. For example `curl -d '{"user": {"username":"value1"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users` to test POSTing JSON to your local api endpoint.

Comment: Thanks again you two. Indeed it seems that Postman did not like my JSON-markup in the request-body. I now got an `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR` while aiming to create a user. It seems to have to do with the `validates_uniqueness_of ` helper, so this is rather unrelated to the original question I posted. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution to the problem I posted:

1. as correctly pointed out by @Nathan Kontny and @fanta, the user_params were missing within the create method of the users_controller.rb.
2. Whenever you try to send an HTTP POST request with software like "Postman" or the likes, make sure that your request content-type is set **application/JSON**. This is important. Otherwise your request will be just plain text.

In Postman this can be achieved by selecting it from the dropdown in the Body-Tab of the request-editor.

[Postman content-type application/JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyZGR.png)